# ios - View is pixelated when scaled down

Tags: ios, uiview, uiimageview, cgaffinetransform, cabasicanimation

I have a UIView that is composed of two UIImageViews. They are concentric circle shapes. When I scale this view down like this:

```
CABasicAnimation *resizeAnimation = [CABasicAnimation animationWithKeyPath:@"transform.scale"];
    resizeAnimation.fromValue = [NSNumber numberWithDouble:1.0];
    resizeAnimation.toValue = [NSNumber numberWithDouble:0.25];
    resizeAnimation.fillMode = kCAFillModeForwards;
    resizeAnimation.removedOnCompletion = NO;
```

The edges of the images get rough and pixelated when scaled down. Is there anything I can do to prevent this or at least minimize it?

Answer (score 0):

Try to set image view's layer minificationFilter to kCAFilterNearest or kCAFilterTrilinear